# Transmute array of objects to class instances

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am returning an array of objects from php and I want to transmute this data into instantiates of a class `ContentData`.

I currently have the following which works, however I have a gut feeling there is a cleaner approach to achieving the outcome.

```
return this.http.post("get-content.php", urlParams)
.map(this.extractData)
.map(array => {
    let newArray = Array<ContentData>();
    array.forEach(obj => {
        newArray.push(new ContentData().deserialize(obj));
    });
    return newArray;
})
.catch(this.handleError)

private extractData(res: Response): any {
    return res.json();
}
```

Is there a cleaner aproach rather than iterating the array data like this?

---

Response from php is:

```
[
{"id":"1","dock_id":"46","type":"TEXT","content":"{\"text\": \"<p>test<\/p>\"}","last_updated":"2017-08-09 03:10:28","json":null},
{"id":"2","dock_id":"46","type":"TEXT","content":"{\"text\": \"<p>test test<\/p>\"}","last_updated":"2017-08-09 03:10:28","json":null}
]
```

Expected output is `[ContentData, ContentData, ...]` (just a 1D array).

```
(2) [ContentData, ContentData]
0 : ContentData {content: "{"text": "<p>test</p>"}", dock_id: "46", type: 0, last_updated: "2017-08-09 03:10:28"}
1 : ContentData {content: "{"text": "<p>test test</p>"}", dock_id: "46", type: 0, last_updated: "2017-08-09 03:10:28"}
length : 2
```

Comment: Am I to understand that you're expecting `ContentData[][]` as your final type?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Just expecting a 1D array, I updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: That's not what you're currently returning though. OK, I'm taking a look.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I have updated the question again with the direct response from the php request.

Comment: Oh, wait, `.map()` isn't what I thought it was. It isn't `[].map` or even `Bluebird.map()`, it's more akin to a Promise's `.then()`. I've posted an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you can do several things:

- Use `async` functions for more linear-looking code
- Use `.map()` instead of for-and-push

Something like this:

```
public async fetchAndProcess(/* args */) {
  try {
    const res = await this.http.post("get-content.php", urlParams); // Assuming fetch
    const json = await res.json();
    return result = json.map(item => new ContentData().deserialize(item));
  } catch (e) { this.handleError(e); }
}
```

Another thing I would do is either create a static method `ContentData.fromSerialized()` or modify `ContentData`'s constructor to accept `item`. But that's more at the realm of code style.

Comment: I'm yet to implement anything using `async` - so this will take me a couple minutes to process. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: @Zze Sure thing, if you need clarification about something, do tell :)

Comment: I don't understand how this works... isn't `item` equal to the array in the response?

Comment: No, normally when talking about `.map()`, we're talking about [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which accepts a callback and iterates the array and applies the callback on each item, returning a new array. I don't know what kind of monad library you're using, but `json` is the array, and `json.map()` is the processing loop.

Comment: No wonder I was so confused..... it was using `Observable.map()` not `Array.prototype.map()`.